# JSP javascript function onclick to different jsp page

Tags: forms, jsp, javascript

I have a form and javascript function to open 2.jsp page but it keeps giving me

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Here is how I do it. I tried to put in only the important parts.

```
<form name = iForm action=1.jsp method=POST>
    <input type="button" value="Button2" name=button2 onclick="OnButton1()"/>
</form>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function OnButton1{
        document.iFrom.action = "2.jsp";
        document.iFrom.target = "_blank";
        document.iFrom.submit();
        return true;
}
< /script>
```

I know a way to open through 'window' but I was wondering if there is this way

Comment: target works on anchor elements, not on form elements. Use a link instead of a form and it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not put parenthesis after your JavaScript function name and you misspelled the form name in your script.

Correct those mistakes and it should work as you might expect.

As well, the target attribute does work for forms.